# Seekbar lagging towards end Android

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have have a seekbar in inside a Liner Layout. This liner layout background image is set dynamically (Image coming from SDCARD). Thumb image is within the application. Progress drawable is transparent color.

There are image view around 6-7 all shows image from the SDCARD (images assigned in onCreate()). Depending upon the seek bar progress we showing particular image view. Seek bar max value is set dynamically (Depending upon imageview i.e.100 * no of imageview).

The problem is seek bar start lagging Just seekbar lagging (thumb movement) for last image view i.e. if max is 800 it lag from 700 to 800.

I am not able to figure out actual reason for lagging. Does any one faced same problem. What will be possible solution or fix to slider?

Thank You

Comment: You need to be more specific, lagging how exactly? The entire UI lags or just the seekbar?

Comment: Just seekbar lagging (thumb movement)...

Comment: I would suggest posting a sample project showing the problem.